# Python3 control of RPi / Piface

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi2

First post. I have had a search around and can't find much info on this, was hoping someone here could help.

For background, I am building a pitstop timing system to asist mechanics with use of their wheel guns / reactions during races. [PIt Stop Rig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAA9E.jpg) . Hopefully you can see in the picture, there are four axles, each with an LED, and each switched.

I am writing a script to run a basic reaction timer using Rpi, Piface Digital 2 and driving it with Python. I have the first iteration working, in that it reads the digital input, and drives the digital outputs. I would now like to make it so it runs the scriput through 5 times, reads the digital input and stores these in variables. If anyone can assit with the Python , I would be really greatful.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    # Pit Stop Reaction Timer

    from time import sleep
    from timeit import default_timer as timer
    import random
    from random import randrange, uniform
    import pifacedigitalio as pifacedigital
    import sys

    pifacedigital.init()
    leds = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    randomNumber1 = [0, 3 , 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2]
    randomNumber2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 4, 3, 8, 12, 10, 11, 9, 8, 6, 7, 10, 5]
    randomLED = random.choice(randomNumber1)
    randomFlash = random.choice(randomNumber2)

    sleepTime = 0.1  # the time in seconds
    rounds = 8
    button4 = 0
    button5 = 1
    button6 = 2
    button7 = 3



   def ledFlash(times, interval):
       i = 0
       # repeat times times ...
       while i < times:
           # turn on LED 1 to 4
           for led in leds:
           pifacedigital.digital_write(0, 0)
           pifacedigital.digital_write(1, 0)
           pifacedigital.digital_write(2, 0)
           pifacedigital.digital_write(3, 0)
           sleep(interval)

          # turn off LED 0 to 4 one at a time with interval intervals ...
           for led in leds:
           pifacedigital.digital_write(0, 1)
           pifacedigital.digital_write(1, 1)
           pifacedigital.digital_write(2, 1)
           pifacedigital.digital_write(3, 1)
           sleep(interval)

       i += 1


     print("Menu:")
     print("=====")
     print("External Button: Start Pit Stop Sim")
     print()
     print("Select the correct hub with the gun to stop the timer")

     while True:
       if pifacedigital.digital_read(0):
       ledFlash(randomFlash, sleepTime)
       pifacedigital.digital_write(randomLED, 0)
       start = timer()
       print("Random LED result", randomLED)
       print("Random number of LED flashes result", randomFlash)
    elif pifacedigital.digital_read(4) and button4 == randomLED:
       end = timer()
       print(end-start)
       sys.exit()
    elif pifacedigital.digital_read(5) and button5 == randomLED:
       end = timer()
       print(end-start)
       sys.exit()
    elif pifacedigital.digital_read(6) and button6 == randomLED:
       end = timer()
       print(end-start)
       sys.exit()
    elif pifacedigital.digital_read(7) and button7 == randomLED:
       end = timer()
       print(end-start)
       sys.exit()
```

Any pointers as to use a loop to get this to iterate 5 times so I can measure and take an average would be great.

Many thanks

Joe.

Comment: Your indentation is off. Did you copy the code correctly? If yes, does the script run? (I'd be surprised). If not, please fix it.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for replying.

The indentation is off as I didn't know how to copy paste here and mashed it all up. The script runs fine on the RPi. 

I have figured work around now, not the prettiest way of doing it, it just runs through a series of 'while' loops, bumping up an increment each time. I will post the code from work on Monday.( with correct indents!)

Again, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Cool, you're welcome. Is there a reason why `randomNumber` 1 and 2 contain repetitions? It means that there's an 18.75% chance of `randomFlash` being 8 but only a 6.25% chance of it being 2. Of course, this could be intentional but if it's not, you could simply delete the lists and write `randomLED = random.randint(0,3)` and `randomFlash = random.randint(2,12)` instead. Also, if you want a new random number for each loop, you should place the call to random inside the while loop. All in all, I think what you want to do is pretty simple but I'm not sure I completely understand the end goal.

Comment: ...and btw. interesting project! :)